# SqlBeginTransaction and wait for delivery

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to use BeginTransaction command to handle Concurrency issues in Vb.net Program

I have been able to save the data into the database without using the 'BeginTransaction' command and it worked fine. But i read about the use of BeginTransaction and the IsolationLevel. I implemented this in my code and this is the error i am getting.

"ExecuteReader requires command to have transaction when connection assigned to command is in pending local transaction. The transaction property of the command has not been initialized."

Below is the code.

```
   Dim conn As New SqlConnection("data source=PRECIOUSMUM\MSSQLSERVER_1; initial catalog=inventory; user id=sade; password=lollypop;")

    Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim tran As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_order_cart.Rows

            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "SELECT  product_id, quantity  FROM tblproducts WHERE (product_id=@product_id) "
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", row.Cells(0).Value)
            End With
            Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            Dim dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim stock As Double
                Dim qty As Double
                Dim stockded As Double
                qty = row.Cells(3).Value
                stock = dt.Rows(0).Item("quantity")
                stockded = stock - qty
                Dim upcmdstock = New SqlCommand
                With upcmdstock
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandText = "UPDATE tblproducts SET quantity=@quantity WHERE (product_id=@product_id)"
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", stockded)
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", row.Cells(0).Value)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With

            End If
            tran.Commit()
            conn.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try
```

I want to ensure the transaction commits and also is there a way i can put "waitfor delay" in the code to ensure the row is locked and the transaction commits fully.

NB: Please dont down vote me

Answer (score 0):

The supplied code is committing the transaction and closing the connection inside the For Each loop:

```vb
conn.Open()
Dim tran As SqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_order_cart.Rows
...
    tran.Commit()
    conn.Close()
Next
```

The first row might succeed, but subsequent rows will fail because the transaction has completed and the connection has been closed.

Comment: If i want the Loop to finish before committing it, i can place it after the Next Loop Right? Also, using the Serializable, Does it prevent other users from reading data? Any other better Isolation level that will not arise into unnecessary loop?

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes: First, if the only reason for the select statement is to get the initial quantity, select only that field, and use ExecuteScalar... there's no need to create a datatable just for a one-row, two-field table. Just get the one value need. 
Secondly, even better, I'd get rid of the transaction and just do the quantity 
adjustment right in the SQL to begin with:

```
UPDATE tblproducts SET quantity = quantity - @quantity where...
```

If you're really still concerned about concurrency at that point, use this as your SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE tblproducts SET quantity = quantity - @quantity where...;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

But if you want the quickest update and release on the data so that others can get to it the fastest, the best thing to do is skip the transactions, and make SQL do the calculation and update together. This is the stuff SQL was build for: data manipulations. Let it do what it does best.